# Google OAuth 2.0: Need application to ask password each time but not consent

Tags: vb.net, authentication, oauth, google-oauth

I've developed a functioning app to perform login via Google OAuth 2.0 and return me the user's name and email. This I'm doing using VB.NET, and without any Google APIs. Only through web requests and a plain web browser control. I perform the following steps:

I create a URI with querystring including client_id, redirect_uri, scope, prompt(=select_account), and response_type.

Then WebBrowser shows me a page where user can select which account to use for login. Afterwards it pushes the user to a consent page for using application. Then after user gives consent, an authorization token is provided by Google, which I use to obtain access token. And then I obtain user information via the access token.

All this works well! However I'm trying to modify this procedure a little bit to match with the requirements of my application. I want to force the user to enter email and password every time the application is run. As per above situation, user enters email password only once and then browser saves it for future. I don't want browser to save it, I want to to ask fresh each time. And as for consent, I want OAuth to ask for consent for the first time only. As per above situation, consent is asked every time application is run.

How do I accomplish this requirement. As per research, there is a parameter called `approval_prompt=force` which forces consent every time and it should be removed. I've checked, its not there. Its put in by Google API. I'm not using APIs, I'm using simple web requests.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Update**
I've managed to code to make OAuth ask for user name and password every time application is run; by clearing the cache created by the web browser control.

**Note** I'm using a 3rd party browser, GeckoFX. By 'webbrowser' control I actually mean GeckoFX. It allows clearing of cache created by it.